# Move files from an array of subfolders to a new directory with same array names

Tags: arrays, powershell

Using powershell I would like to search through an array of sub-folders in multiple directories containing 1 folder called incoming and move the files from incoming to a staging area using the same folder name as its source.

IE: Files arrive in folders like this:

z:\folder1\incoming\file.*, z:\folder2\incoming\file.*, z:\folder3\sub1\incoming\file.*, z:\folder3\sub2\incoming\file.* etc.

Then would need to be moved to a staging area using the same folder structure:

\nas\staging\folder1\incoming\file.*, \nas\staging\folder2\incoming\file.*, \nas\staging\folder3\sub1\incoming\file.*, \nas\staging\folder3\sub2\incoming\file.* etc.

Basically the only sub-folders i want to extract from are the ones containing the "Incoming" folder with files. Since there is no predefined folder names other than the sub-folder "Incoming" i would need to loop through every folder within Z:.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I was able to come up with this which affectively moves the folder structure excluding "outgoing" to the staging directory which is great but in my environment there would be to many exclusions to check for this way. Also is there a chance i can move the files to specific folders from maybe a list if needed?

```
$from = 'C:\ftp'
$to = 'C:\staging'

$excludeMatch = @("Outgoing")
Get-ChildItem -Path $from -Recurse -Exclude $exclude |
      where { $excludeMatch -eq $null -or $_.FullName.Replace($from, "") -notmatch $excludeMatch } |
      Copy-Item -Destination {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
          Join-Path $to $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($from.length)
        } else {
          Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring($from.length)
        }
       } -Force -Exclude $exclude
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a fairly straightforward task with PowerShell, but people here aren't going to write the whole script for you.

Comment: This is probably better solved using Robocopy. Robocopy can copy files based on a name match pattern and maintain the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sooooo, what we need is, to identify any file whos parent directory is called 'incoming'? There are at least two ways of solving this I can think of, but there may be a neater, more idiomatic solution that eludes me.

**Method 1 - Identify 'incoming' folders then copy contents**

```
get-childitem -Path $from -recurse -Filter "incoming" |
    where-object { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

If you are using PowerShell 3, I believe (read 'untested') this could be shortened to

```
get-childitem -Path $from -recurse -Filter "incoming" -Directory
```

Either of the above should result in a stream of 'directory' objects, all of which are 'incoming' folders. For each one, copy the files to appropriate destination.

**Method 2 - Identify all files then process those whos folder is 'incoming'**

```
get-childitem -path $from -recurse |
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    where-object { (Split-Path $_.Directory -Leaf) -eq "incoming" }
```

This results in a stream of 'file' objects, all of which are in a folder called 'incoming'. For each one, copy to appropriate destination.